# Help with plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics

can anyone help me with how to create similar to these plots using Mathematica or Matlab?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post  any source of such pictures or directly post some analytic expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [ReliefPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReliefPlot.html)

```
n = 4;

ReliefPlot[Table[Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -n, n, .025}, {j, -n, n, .025}],
 ColorFunction -> None,
 DataRange -> {{-n, n}, {-n, n}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Vx", "Vy"},
 FrameTicks -> True,
 LightingAngle -> Pi/4]
```

[image]